# Common Lisp - Collect 'firsts' from nested lists of lists

Tags: list, tree, common-lisp

Beeing new to CL and having tried several mapping approaches I still couldn't figure it out.

Is it possible to collect from a nested list all first elements as shown below? Conceptually speaking:
How can one gather a parent node and all its child-nodes from a (not necessarily binary) tree-like structure in CL.

```
(defparameter *nested-list* (list "a" (list "b" (list "c" "d"))
                                      (list "e" (list "f")
                                                (list "g" "h"))))
```

The function call...

```
(defun collect-firsts (*nested-list*)
  ; ...
)
```

...should result in something like this:

```
:-> (('start "a") ("a" "b" "e") ("b" "c") ("c" "d")
     ("e" "f" "g")("f") ("g" "h"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
(defun immediate-children (object &aux (result '()))
  (labels ((f (object) 
             (cond
               ((consp object)
                (push (list* (first object)
                             (mapcar #'f (rest object)))
                      result)
                (first object))
               (t object))))
    (f object)
    result))
```

```
CL-USER> (immediate-children *nested-list*)
(("a" "b" "e") ("e" "f" "g") ("g" "h") ("f") ("b" "c") ("c" "d"))
```

The result isn't exactly what you provided in the question, but I think it still makes sense.  It includes `("f")` in the results, which is probably reasonable, since there's a node labeled `"f"` with no children.  The traversal order is different too, but if this is just a list of lists of the form `(parent child+)`, then that's probably not a problem.

Comment: Of course you are right about the additional ("f"), I've corrected the output. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following in emacs and in common-lisp.
The output can be inspected at https://ideone.com/hNEQTJ.

```lisp
(defparameter *nested-list* (list "a" (list "b" (list "c" "d"))
                              (list "e" (list "f")
                                        (list "g" "h"))))

(defun collect-firsts (*nested-list*)
  (let ((ret `((start ,(car *nested-list*)))))
    (labels ((recursion (x)
             ;; 1st generate list of the name and the cars
             (setq ret (append ret
                       (list (cons (car x)
                           (mapcar (lambda (el)
                                 (if (listp el) (car el) el))
                               (cdr x))))))
             ;; 2nd recurse if required
             (mapc (lambda (el)
                 (when (and (listp el) (cdr el))
                   (recursion el))) x)
             ret))
      (recursion *nested-list*)
    ret)))

(collect-firsts *nested-list*)
```

Comment: Please, don't do this.  It's almost like answering a Java question with C# or JavaScript.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Thanks for informing me that the code did not run in CL. I've modified it so that it runs in CL as well as in emacs-lisp.

Comment: Don't `setq` unbound variables in Common Lisp.  It has undefined behaviour, especially regarding specialness of the resulting variable.  Here, `defparameter` seems right.

Comment: `Defparameter` seems right for the toplevel, that is.  Use `let` inside the body.  If you format your code according to its structure, it also gets much easier to understand (I have not idea what you are doing with the `ret` there).